# How is it that complement of 0xff is not 0x00?

Tags: c

I don't understand how the complement of 0xff is not 0x00.
Here is the code:

```
uint8_t u8a;

u8a = 0xff;

printf( "%d\n", ~u8a );
if( ~u8a == 0x00 )
    printf( "Equal\n" );
else
    printf( "Not Equal\n" );
```

The `printf` statement displays "-256" and "Not Equal".
What am I missing in my understanding?
If it gets promoted to `int` type, why does it get promoted to `int` type?

Comment: Your `printf` is printing `~u8a` so there's no way it's 255. What does your current `printf` that you're showing print?

Comment: You already have the answer. And are you asking why C language code behaves like C language code? Or do you use a system with `INT_MAX == SCHAR_MAX`? And how would this be specific to embedded systems?

Comment: @Olaf - I see.  This material could come up embedded or non-embedded.  I just happen to be stuck while I am doing embedding programming.  Thanks for the point.

Comment: Another way to express the conditional is `if ((~u8a & 0xff) == 0)`. (which will also eliminate your compiler warning of `warning: promoted ~unsigned is always non-zero [-Wsign-compare]`)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Prior to applying the `~` operator, the value of `u8a` is promoted to `int`.

From section 6.3.1.1 of the [C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf):

> *2* The following may be used in an expression wherever an `int` or `unsigned int` may be used:
>
> - An object  or  expression  with  an 
>     integer  type  (other  than `int` or `unsigned int` ) whose  integer 
>     conversion  rank  is  less  than  or  equal  to  the  rank  of `int`
>     and `unsigned int` .
> - A bit-field of type `_Bool` , `int` , `signed int` ,or `unsigned int` .
>
> If  an `int` can  represent  all  values  of
>   the  original  type  (as  restricted  by  the  width,  for  a
>   bit-field),  the  value  is  converted  to  an `int` ; otherwise,  it 
>   is  converted  to  an `unsigned int` . These  are  called  the
>   *integer promotions* .
>
> All  other  types  are  unchanged  by  the integer promotions.

Because a `uint8_t` has a lower rank than `int`, and because all possible values can fit in an `int`, any expression involving this type will always be promoted to `int` as per the standard.

So assuming an `int` is 4 bytes the value `0xff` is promoted to `0x000000ff`.  Applying the `~` operator to that yields `0xffffff00`.

So when you print this value using the `%d` operator, it is interpreted (rightfully) as -256.  Similarly, this value is not the same as `0x00`, so "Not Equal" is printed.

To get the result you expect, you need to cast the result of the `~` operator back to `uint8_t`.  Also, you should use the `PRIu8` format specifier macro to `printf` to accurately reflect the value you're passing in.

```
printf( "%" PRIu8 "\n", (uint8_t)~u8a );
if( (uint8_t)~u8a == 0x00 )
    printf( "Equal\n" );
else
    printf( "Not Equal\n" );
```

Result:

```
0
Equal
```

Comment: That's more like it, I still like the suggestion of using `inttypes.h` `PRIu8` as the format specifier `:)`

Comment: @dbush - Is there a way not to promote to int?  Is there a way to do the complement within the type of uint8_t?  If that is possible, that should save some execution time? Or is this the C way that we are stuck with?

Comment: @Nguaial No, there's no way to prevent it.  That's the way the standard says the language has to behave.  As far as execution time, it's highly unlikely something like that would have an effect, and unless you have specific evidence that there's a performance problem you shouldn't be worried about those types of micro-optimizations.

Answer (score -1):

In C, all arithmetic is done with values no smaller than an `int` (see [here](http://publications.gbdirect.co.uk/c_book/chapter2/expressions_and_arithmetic.html)). This means that the 8-bit value will be extended to 32-bits when you do the `~` operation.

If you were to assign the result to a variable, it would save it with the correct variable size, but since your evaluating it in the `if` statement the `printf` function, it uses a 32-bit value.

Comment: Perhaps suggesting the *format specifier* of `%hhu` would be appropriate or using the `PRIu8` from `inttypes.h`?

Comment: There is no guarantee `int` has 32 bits.

Comment: int can be 16 bits.